# AForge.NET neural network

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am a beginner in neural networks. I want to implement the Kohonen network.  I found the framework AForg.Net (library for neural network) but I don't know haw to use it to get results.

Comment: many developers have this same question, myself included.

Comment: Is there any documentation about the Library? You could start from there :)

Comment: @FelipeOriani Library/Documentation/Books about neural networks are very complex and difficult to beginners :/

Comment: yes actually there documentation that explains the library but  without the use

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Kohonen I strongly recommend studying the [Neuquant](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NEUQUANT.HTML) algorithm. It's a remarkably practical application of neural networks on an easy-to-understand problem (color quantization). And there is a very clean C# implementation of it in this [simple yet powerful palette quantizer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C) project.

What's more is that project implements a variety of quantization algorithms so you can see how they work compared to the Neuquant algorithm and gain a deeper understanding of the strengths and weaknesses of Kohonen neural networks.

Comment: I have to implement Kohonen algorithm to train the neural network for a specified comportment of a resident in a smart home to automate his comportment

Comment: @user3603831 my advice is to study its application to a simpler problem such as in my proposed answer. this is to appreciate better what you can do with Kohonen. then you could focus on your smart home problem with new abilities in your toolbox.

Comment: Your NeuQuant link is dead, but I think these link to the same material: http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0954-898X/5/3/003 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232079905_Kohonen_neural_networks_for_optimal_colour_quantization